# Python : Assert that variable is instance method?

Tags: python, methods, instance, assert

How can one check if a variable is an instance method or not? I'm using python 2.5.

Something like this:

```
class Test:
    def method(self):
        pass

assert is_instance_method(Test().method)
```

Comment: What's wrong with asking here?

Comment: Reading the source isn't any help - presumably he's writing some code that needs to know the answer at runtime. Possibly iterating through all attrs on an object, for instance.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

[`inspect.ismethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.ismethod) is what you want to find out if you definitely have a method, rather than just something you can call.

```
import inspect

def foo(): pass

class Test(object):
    def method(self): pass

print inspect.ismethod(foo) # False
print inspect.ismethod(Test) # False
print inspect.ismethod(Test.method) # True
print inspect.ismethod(Test().method) # True

print callable(foo) # True
print callable(Test) # True
print callable(Test.method) # True
print callable(Test().method) # True
```

`callable` is true if the argument if the argument is a method, a function (including `lambda`s), an instance with `__call__` or a class.

Methods have different properties than functions (like `im_class` and `im_self`).  So you want

```
assert inspect.ismethod(Test().method)
```

Comment: +1, inspect is good (and that "defiantly" typo actually reads well;-).

Comment: Using Python 3.5, `inspect.ismethod(Test.method)` returns False.

Comment: You should use an instance of test sinse it is an instance method 
```
inspect.ismethod(Test().method)
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to know if it is precisely an instance method use the following function. (It considers methods that are defined on a metaclass and accessed on a class class methods, although they could also be considered instance methods)

```
import types
def is_instance_method(obj):
    """Checks if an object is a bound method on an instance."""
    if not isinstance(obj, types.MethodType):
        return False # Not a method
    if obj.im_self is None:
        return False # Method is not bound
    if issubclass(obj.im_class, type) or obj.im_class is types.ClassType:
        return False # Method is a classmethod
    return True
```

Usually checking for that is a bad idea. It is more flexible to be able to use any *callable()* interchangeably with methods.