# How can I tell if a given method is a classmethod or instancemethod in Python?

Tags: python, class

Checking to see if m.im_self is the class works some of the time but doesn't seem to be 100% reliable (ex. if you use multiple decorators on a method.)

Comment: Please provide code examples of working/non-working scenarios.

Comment: What's wrong with reading the source?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259963/python-assert-that-variable-is-instance-method

Comment: Provocative answer, as you didn't specify what you want to achieve: Why do you even care? If you can invoke it - you're fine. If you can't - well, that can happen regardless whether it's a classmethod, staticmethod or instance method.

Answer (score 2):

If it's a bound method *on the class* then it's a classmethod.

```
from inspect import ismethod, isclass
def isclassmethod( m ):
 return ismethod(m) and isclass(m.__self__)
```