# Pickle all attributes except one

Tags: python, pickle

What is the best way to write a `__getstate__` method that pickles *almost* all of an object's attributes, but excludes a few?

I have an object with many properties, including one that references an instancemethod.  instancemethod's are not pickleable, so I'm getting an error when I try to pickle this object:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = 'spam'
        self.b = 'eggs'
        self.c = 42
        self.fn = self.my_func
    def my_func(self):
        print 'My hovercraft is full of eels'

import pickle
pickle.dumps(Foo())              # throws a "can't pickle instancemethod objects" TypeError
```

This `__getstate__` method fixes this, but then I have to manually include all the properties I want to serialize:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return { 'a': self.a, 'b': self.b, 'c': self.c }
```

That's not very scalable or maintainable if I have an object with many attributes or that changes frequently.

The only alternative I can think of is some kind of helper function that iterates through an object's properties and adds them (or not) to the dictionary, based on the type.

Comment: +1 for hovercraft reference (and it is a worthy question, besides ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> The only alternative I can think of is some kind of helper function that iterates through an object's properties and adds them (or not) to the dictionary, based on the type.

Yeah, I think that's pretty much what you're left with, if you want enough "magic" to allow yourself to be lazy (and/or allow for dynamically added attributes). Keep in mind that "`pickle` can't handle this" isn't the only reason you might not want to include something in the pickled state.

But it's not as hard as you seem to think, assuming you have code for the "should I pickle this?" logic:

```
def __getstate__(self):
  return {k:v for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items() if should_pickle(v)}
```

Comment: What about parent classes ? Will your getstate function do the right thing for the parent attributes ?

Comment: A [dict comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) is slightly neater here: `{k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.iteritems() if should_pickle(v)}`

Comment: and @Venza: I think it will play nicely with inheritance. (It won't include any class attributes though.)

Comment: Updated to modernize the code, since the OP wasn't tagged as 2.x anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Using [`is_instance_method`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259963/python-assert-that-variable-is-instance-method/1260881#1260881) from an earlier answer:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    return dict((k, v) for k, v in self.__dict__.iteritems()
                       if not is_instance_method(getattr(self, k)))
```

Although the `is_instance_method` operation can also be performed less "magically" by taking an known instance method, say `my_func`, and taking its type.

```
def __getstate__(self):
    instancemethod = type(self.my_func)
    return dict((k, v) for k, v in self.__dict__.iteritems()
                       if not isinstance(getattr(self, k), instancemethod))
```

Answer (score 4):

You could always just remove the bad items:

```
def __getstate__(self):
    state = self.__dict__
    del state[...]
    return state
```

Comment: But this would modify the original object, which I don't want.  I suppose I could do a deepcopy of `self.__dict__` and remove attributes from the copy.  That might introduce other problems, though.

Comment: @Mike: oops, forgot to copy the dict. Yes, the intention was to copy it first.

Comment: @Mike: note that you only need a shallow copy, since you never modify the keys and values (only the dict itself).

Comment: edited for `.copy()`. Then I think this is an elegant answer to the original question, which focuses on a single or few attributes known by name. Those answers with list/dict comprehensions and expensive type checks are unnecessary painful.

Answer (score 1):

I'd cut to the root of your problem, and try to serialize the so-called 'un-pickleable' items first.
To do this, I'd use [dill](http://pythonhosted.org/dill), which can serialize almost anything in python. Dill also has [some good tools](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/blob/master/dill/detect.py) for helping you understand what is causing your pickling to fail when your code fails.

```
>>> import dill
>>> dill.loads(dill.dumps(your_bad_object))
>>> ...
>>> # if you get a pickling error, use dill's tools to figure out a workaround
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(your_bad_object, depth=0)
>>> dill.detect.badobjects(your_bad_object, depth=1)
>>> ...
```

If you absolutely wanted to, you could use dill's `badobjects` (or one of the other detection functions) to dive recursively into your object's reference chain, and pop out the unpickleable objects, instead of calling it at at every depth, as above.

Answer (score 1):

**`__slots__` solution**

If you are using slots, you can avoid repeating members to exclude with:

```
class C(object):
    _pickle_slots = ['i']
    __slots__ = _pickle_slots + ['j']
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j
    def __getstate__(self):
        return (None, {k:getattr(self, k) for k in C._pickle_slots })

o = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(C(1, 2), -1))

# i is there
assert o.i == 1

# j was excluded
try:
    o.j
except:
    pass
else:
    raise
```

Tested in Python 2.7.6.

Answer (score 0):

For the your specific case (preventing a function from getting pickled), use this:

`self.__class__.fn = self.__class__.my_func`

Now, instead of adding a function to an instance of a class, you've added it to the class itself, thus the function won't get pickled. This won't work if you want each instance to have its own version of `fn`.

My scenario was that I wanted to selectively add `get_absolute_url` to some Django models, and I wanted to define this in an abstract `BaseModel` class. I had `self.get_absolute_url = …` and ran into the `pickle` issue. Just added `__class__` to the assignment solved the issue in my case.