# How to distinguish between function and a method in decorator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write decorator that will do different job depending on that whether it will be decorating method or a function.

I tried something like this:

```
def dec(f):
    def wrapper(*v, **kv):
        if '__class__' in dir(f):
            text = "Its a method"
        else:
            text = "Its a function"
        print(text)
        return f(*v, **kv)
    return wrapper


class A:

    @dec
    def f(self):
        pass

@dec
def f():
    pass

a = A()

a.f()
f()
```

It returns:

```
Its a method
Its a method
```

But this won't work since all functions also have also `__class__` attribute :) I tried also to do `inspect.ismethod` on A.f but A.f is treaten just like function but in A namespace and it return of course false. It would return True if we have done inspect.ismethod(a.f) where `a` is instance of `A` but I can't wait to have instance.

Comment: At decoration time all you have is a function. Only when *looking up the name* is a function bound to an instance and you get a method.

Comment: In other words, you can stick any old function onto a class and it'll work as a method. There is nothing about the class definition that makes functions methods at that class loading time.

Comment: The `__class__` attribute on a function has nothing to do with the custom class you are defining this on.

Comment: There is, therefor, no way you can detect if you are wrapping a function or a method. Why do you need this? The only thing you can be certain about is that a method will have an instance passed in as the first argument. Yes, this means you can take any function and pass in an instance, manually, and you cannot detect the difference.

Comment: Check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1259963/python-assert-that-variable-is-instance-method) answer

Comment: @ArthurVaiselbuh this wont solve's the OP's use case - at the point where it's decorated, it's a always a function, you only get a method when the name is looked up on the class or instance, cf https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Martijn already explained in his comments, being defined in a class statement's body doesn't make a function a method - the method object is created at lookup time, as explained [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/FromFunctionToMethod) - so what you are decorating is and will always (well almost cf below) be a function. FWIW, Python's "methods" are just thin wrappers around the function, class and (eventually) instance.

The only case where you might get something else than a function are classmethods and staticmethods (in which case you'll get resp. a `classmethod` or `staticmethod` object instead), and even then it depends on the decorators order.

If you want to get at the method's current instance (or class) in your decorator, you know that it will always be the first positional argument - but this might not be of great help... To make a long story short, you have to either explicitely tell your decorator if it should treat the function as plain function or method, or decorate it with a custom descriptor in which case you'll know if the function has - or not - been looked up as a method... A naïve implementation migh look like this:

```
class MyDecorator(object):
    def __init__(self, func, instance=None):
        self.func = func
        self.instance = instance

    def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
        if self.instance:
            print "is method - instance : %s" % self.instance
            args = (self.instance,) + args
        else:
            print "is_function"

        return self.func(*args, **kw)

    def __get__(self, instance, cls):
        return type(self)(self.func, instance)
```

Comment: Thank you, and Martijn very much :)