# Trying to Print Values of Attributes... Code Needs Improvement

Tags: python, python-3.x, attributes, getattr

```
class User():

    def __init__(self, first, last, location, gender):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.location = location
        self.gender = gender
        self.loginattempt = 0

    def mmplusattempt(self):
        self.loginattempt += 1

    def mmresetattempt(self):
        self.loginattempt = 0


    def mmdescribe(self):
        attributes = [a for a in dir(self) if not a.startswith(('__', 'mm'))]
        for att in attributes:
            print(att + ": " + str(getattr(self, att))) 


new = User('david', 'johnson', 'usa', 'male')
new.mmdescribe()
```

output:

```
└─$ python3 classuser.py
first: david
gender: male
last: johnson
location: usa
loginattempt: 0
```

The problem is, or was that `attributes = [a for a in dir(self) if not a.startswith('__')]` was returning all the attributes including `plusattempt` `resetattempt` `describe` which I don't want. I did not want to print any of the methods so I thought maybe I can make all the method names start with `mm` and filter them out using `a.startswith(('__', 'mm'))]`. Now this definitely works, but I feel there has to be a better way that I can't think of right now. Also if there was an attribute (that is not a method) that I didn't want to print, I would have to add `mm` to the name, which is not very efficient.

1. How would I be able to print the attributes of `new` excluding the methods? (Other than the way I showed) I'm sure there is a more elegant way to write this.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1260997/3817068) will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using `vars`, and implementing `__str__` rather than using your `mmdescribe` method:

```
class User:

    def __init__(self, first, last, location, gender):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.location = location
        self.gender = gender
        self.loginattempt = 0

    def plusattempt(self):
        self.loginattempt += 1

    def resetattempt(self):
        self.loginattempt = 0

    def __str__(self):
        return "\n".join(f"{k}: {v}" for k, v in vars(self).items())

user = User("david", "johnson", "usa", "male")
print(user)
```

Output:

```
first: david
last: johnson
location: usa
gender: male
loginattempt: 0
>>>
```

Comment: did not think of `__str__`, I think this is the solution

Answer (score 0):

IMO you're trying to be too clever where the simple choice is easier to understand and works fine:

```py
    def describe(self):
        print(f'first: {self.first}')
        print(f'last: {self.last}')
        print(f'location: {self.location}')
        print(f'gender: {self.gender}')
```

If you have a very large set of descriptive properties you may consider storing them in an ordered container to avoid having to write out a print statement for each property. (Adding validation to the constructor arguments is left as an exercise for the reader.)

```py
class User():
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        # use an OrderedDict to maintain order when calling `describe`
        from collections import OrderedDict
        self.descriptors = OrderedDict((key, val) for key, val in kwargs.items())
        self.loginattempt = 0

    def describe(self):
        for key, val in self.descriptors.items():
            print(f'{key}: {val}')

>>> u = User(first='david', last='johnson', location='usa', gender='male')
>>> u.describe()
first: david
last: johnson
location: usa
gender: male
```

Just remember that at the end of the day, code that's hard to write is inconvenient right now but code that's hard to read is a nightmare forever.

Comment: `you're trying to be too clever`  can never be too clever haha, but whenever I feel like I am, I bring the problem here to see if I really am trying to be too clever or there is an answer